# Kronecker Delta help

Tags: kronecker-delta

*Find the value of $\delta_{ii}\delta_{jk}\delta_{jk}$.*

Apparently this is $9$, but I can't see why:

$\delta_{ii} = 3$ (as in this case this is defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

$\delta_{jk}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{jk}$

$\delta_{ii}\delta_{jk} = 3\delta_{jk}$

but is this not just 3 x the identity matrix? Why is this a direct number?

Comment: When you write $\delta_{jk}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{jk}$, you fail to appropriately account for the summation convention

Comment: How do you mean? Is this not just the notation for the identity matrix multiplied by itself?

Comment: Let's start with this: why is $\delta_{ii} = 3$?

Comment: Oh I think I get it. Delta_ii is 3 because delta_ij is defined to be 1 if i = j and 0 if i =/ j. Thus it is just the Trace so delta_ii is 3. Doing the summation convention then it's 3 x 2 sums summing across k and j. 2/3 of each of these terms are 0 because j =/ k, thus it's 3 (1+1+1) = 3 x 3 = 9. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first 3 sentences; it doesn't look like you explain why $\delta_{ii}$ should refer to the trace of the matrix denoted by $\delta_{ij}$. The 2 sentences after that seem correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the summation, $i,j,k$ each appear twice. According to the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), we take a sum over every variable. That is, the expression should be interpreted as
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3 \delta_{ii} \delta_{jk}\delta_{jk}
= 
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3 \delta_{ii} \delta_{jk}.
$$
We can see that this sum is indeed equal to $9$.